# How to open the dialog box continuously without overwriting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I am trying to display the dialog box inside the for loop, but last one is always displayed. It was overwriting the existing one.

Is there any alternative way to display the dialog one by one? For example, the for loop size is two. While in the iteration the first one is opened. If I close the first one then the second one will be opened like that.

Following is the code snippet I am using:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#warningMessage").dialog({
    dialogClass: "no-close",
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "YES": function() {
        var me = jQuery(this);
        me.dialog("close");
      },
      "NO": function() {
        var me = jQuery(this);
        me.dialog("close");
      },
    }
  });
  var sample = ["AAAA", "BBBB"];
  for (i in sample) {
    $("#warningMessage").html(sample[i]);
    $("#warningMessage").dialog("open");
  }


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eEa1kEtgK9ZL6h60VXwDsJ2rxYCwfxi40VZ9E0XwoEA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="warningMessage">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="warningMessage">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#warningMessage").dialog({
    dialogClass: "no-close",
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: 
    {
        "YES" : function(){
          var me = jQuery(this);
          me.dialog("close");
        },
        "NO" : function(){
          var me = jQuery(this);
          me.dialog("close");
        },
    }
  });
var sample = ["AAAA","BBBB"];
  for(i in sample){
    $("#warningMessage").html(sample[i]);
    $("#warningMessage").dialog("open");
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please include all relevant code to OP

Comment: There is only one dialog box in this code .. you should use different boxes for this purpose

Comment: @sherin Jose. I want to display the dialog dynamically based on the for loop size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a queue like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var queue = [];

    $(".warningMessage").dialog({
        dialogClass: "no-close",
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "YES": function() {
                var me = jQuery(this);
                me.dialog("close");
            },
            "NO": function() {
                var me = jQuery(this);
                me.dialog("close");
            },
        }
    }).on("dialogclose", function(event, ui) {
        if (queue.length)
            $(".warningMessage").html(queue.shift()).dialog("open");
    });
    var sample = ["AAAA", "BBBB"];
    for (i in sample) {
        queue.push(sample[i]);
    }
    $(".warningMessage").html(queue.shift()).dialog("open");
});
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/dno04zpz/17/